# XAMPP Joomla Vhost - Dashboard not found

Tags: php, apache, joomla, vhosts

What I want:

I want to start Joomla with this URL: "joomla.localhost"
All files from joomla are copied in this directory:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla

In my

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName joomla.localhost
    ServerAlias joomla.localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla"
</VirtualHost>
```

And in my

> C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

In my

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       joomla.localhost
```

When I navigate to http://joomla.localhost/installation 
everything is ok. I can install joomla. All is fine.
After the installation I delete the installation folder.
But when I try http://joomla.localhost joomla will redirect to http://joomla.localhost/dashboard - yeah because of

```
header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
```

in the index.php.
But - I got Object not found ... so what is wrong?
Is there a specific entry in my apache required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault.
Joomla creates this PHP (index.php):

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ('on' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'])) {
        $uri = 'https://';
    } else {
        $uri = 'http://';
    }
    $uri .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    header('Location: '.$uri.'/dashboard/');
    exit;
?>
Something is wrong with the XAMPP installation :-(
```

I don't know why. After reinstall everything is fine!